# Download pdf files from URL and save it in a particular folder in android (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, local-storage

I want to download a pdf file from a given URL and save it in a particular folder. Till now I am able to download the required file and store in the 'Downloads' folder, also I am able to create my custom directory "AldoFiles" but I am not able to store the files in the custom directory.

This is my attempt:

```
 private void downloadPdf() {

        try {
            url = new URL(pdfURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},RequestCode);
        }

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/AldoFiles");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File pdfDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Download/AldoFiles/");
            pdfDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url + ""));
        request.setTitle(fileName);
        request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }
```

Comment: by custom directory do you mean outside the Download folder? if yes then check if your app target version is 29 or greater. cause after 29 API (Q) it uses Scope Storage, which doesn't allow app to access public directory directly. you can read about it using following link [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Aldofiles/" +fileName) Do not yourself try to create that directory. Remove that code.

Comment: @blackapps Thank You so much. Now it works exactly the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @blackapps I solved the issue:

```
try {
    url = new URL(bookURL);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url + ""));
request.setTitle(fileName);
request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "AldoFiles/" + fileName);
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: It creates some files at 0 bytes...